# How to run or build a java program using wsl 2

Tags: java, build, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use wsl 2 to run java programs, and I will be writing the code in sublime text 3. I have already installed java in wsl 2, but don't know how to run a program through it built in sublime.

Comment: What environments have you successfully run Java programs in in the past?

Comment: Why do you want to do it like this?

Comment: @tgdavies, I have used jGrasp for Java previously.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I believe that this can help me gain experience in using this type of interface in case I run into a headless interface in the future.

Comment: @caleb that is probably true but I would save that particular exercise until you have more experience with writing web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, copy the java file to the linux system, the windows disk can be copied from the mnt directory
[image]

Make sure you have successfully installed the Java environment

**Use the javac command to compile the .java file**,
**Use java command to execute .class file**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I wasn't sure how to use the javac command, but I was able to get it working!